# Rubocop: Exclude files from a list given on command line

Tags: git, rubocop, pre-commit

I run rubocop from my pre-commit hook script:

```
bin/bundle exec rubocop ${FILES}
```

with `${FILES}` being the list of files staged for commit. This does not, however, honour the contents of the `AllCops/Exclude` section in `rubocop.yml`.

Since there are files that will always generate offences (e.g. schema.rb), is there a way to make the config `Exclude` section precede the command line parameters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`rubocop` has command-line option `--force-exclusion` which excludes files specified in the `.rubocop.yml` `Exclude` section. This was added on [pull request 922](https://github.com/rubocop/rubocop/pull/922).

Comment: Been searching for an answer to this one. Thanks for posting!

Answer (score 0):

Not that I know, but I agree there should be (or it should be easier).

A few issues are [already opened](https://github.com/rubocop-hq/rubocop/issues/7819) about that. Maybe splitting that setting in two (e.g. with a `AllCops/AlwaysExclude` or a `AllCops/ExcludeByDefault`) is needed.

There is a `inherit_mode` option but I'm not 100% sure how it works or if [it could help](https://github.com/rubocop-hq/rubocop/issues/7230)

Answer (score 0):

I edited my pre-commit script to generate a temporary Rubocop config, that inherits from the main one. The temporary config only contains the `AllCopsInclude` section, which seems to work fine with `AllCops/Exclude` in the main config. No need to tamper with `inherit_mode`.

```
TEMP_CONFIG=/tmp/rubocop-`date +%s`.yml
RUBOCOP_CONFIG=`realpath .rubocop.yml`
cat << EOF > $TEMP_CONFIG
inherit_from: $RUBOCOP_CONFIG
AllCops:
  Include:
EOF
for file in "${FILES[@]}"; do
    echo "    - $file" >> $TEMP_CONFIG
done
bin/bundle exec rubocop -a -c $TEMP_CONFIG
rm $TEMP_CONFIG
```